# Encrypt XML file out of a Dataset

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

I have a winforms application that connects to a couple of databases. However, I would like my app to be used even when the user is not connected to the internet. I had been writing datasets to XML files locally and reading them in based on the user preference whether to download from the database or use a local data file.

```
DataSet.WriteXml(localPath)
```

As the application is improving, I would like to encrypt the XML file to prevent the user from looking inside (There is a bunch of data in there but the application selectively displays data based on access levels assigned to users). I looked into 'Rijndael Managed' and got a prototype working based on [Encrypt/Decrypt Files in VB.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12092/Encrypt-Decrypt-Files-in-VB-NET-Using-Rijndael). I have not been able to figure how to pass in a stream to cryptography classes without them ever being saved to the disk.

Right now, I save the xml file out of the Dataset to a temporary directory and construct a new stream and pass it in to CrypotoStream which then writes an encrypted file to the desired location.

I am looking for a solution to directly pass in the stream without ever writing it to the disk. Please suggest.

Comment: There's a form of DataSet.WriteXml that takes a stream. Use that to write to a MemoryStream, then feed the stream to your crypto class. You should not use RjindaelManged as it will generate security warnings in certain environments, use AesManaged instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a better thing to use would be the EncryptedXml Class

[EncryptedXml Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.xml.encryptedxml.aspx)
Encryption can entail different approaches for cryptographic strength, key bases, etc. Follow the examples in the MSDN documentation. This is not a short implementation, but it works extremely well.

other alternatives

Write into a MemoryStream and use MemoryStream.ToArray();

to read the encrypted stream

Just use the CryptoStream to load the DataSet.

refer to this like to read/decrypt 
[Read/decrypt encrypted XML file and then process internally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10539670/read-decrypt-encrypted-xml-file-and-then-process-internally)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like [MemoryStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx) may be what you are looking for.